# how to refer lB2B_Checkout_finalCartItem child name to parent lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components

`</c-l-b2-b_-checkout_-final-cart-item>` I used this for child name reference in parent, it gives error

> /c/lB2B_Checkout_FinalCartItem/lB2B_Checkout_finalCartItem.js:0,0 : LWC1010: Failed to resolve entry for module "lB2B_Checkout_finalCartItem".

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Thank you for the error text, but you need to please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/363501/edit) your question to also add information about what you have attempted so far. *(From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): "Your question should include **...(the code, metadata, or design, in its current form). and/or the research and work you’ve done so far on the issue.** ")*

Answer (score 1):

The file names are case sensitive. Notice, for your child, in your file path:

```
lB2B_Checkout_FinalCartItem
lB2B_Checkout_finalCartItem.js
```

Here, `F` in the file path doesn't match `f` in the JavaScript file. This should prevent deployment of the child component. You'll also need to make sure, for the parent component, that the name matches correctly based on the [kebab rule](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_components_folder).

It's recommended that you don't use these weird types of names:

> You can use underscores in component folder names, but they don’t map to kebab case in markup. The names are legal because the namespace is separated with a hyphen, but most users expect hyphens instead of underscores in a web component name. For example, this component’s markup references the my_component component. It’s legal, it just looks a little odd.

I would recommend that you refactor the component name to read a bit easier. For example, I'd consider the name `b2bCheckoutFinalCartItem` which would written like `c-b2b-checkout-final-cart-item` when used in code, which is easier to write and harder to mess up.